# Factor irreducible polynomial in Z[x] and R[x]

Tags: abstract-algebra, factoring, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

I've got a couple of problems from an old exam in abstract algebra that I have difficulty in understanding.

1) Write the polynomial $2x^3 - 10$ as a product of irreducible elements in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, and list the irreducible elements in this factorization.

2) Write the polynomial $2x^3 - 10$ as a product of irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, and list the irreducible polynomials in this factorization.

Should I set $F_1 = \mathbb{Z}[x]$ and  $F_2 = \mathbb{Q}[x]$ and do polynomial division to find it with the extension fields, and list the elements in the field? Even so, I don't see how this can be done for the  $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Obviously,
$$2x^3 - 10$$
$$2(x^3 - 5)$$
$$...$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, both $2$ and $x^3-5$ are irreducible, so you can't factor further than $$
  2x^3 - 10 = 2(x^3 - 5) \text{.}
$$
The reason you can't factor $x^3 - 5$ further is that if it had any more factors, one of them would need to have degree $1$, meaning $x^3 - 5$ would have a zero in $\mathbb{Z}$, which it doesn't.

The same argument works over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, but you now need to use that $\sqrt[3]{5}$ isn't rational.

Comment: The difference is that $2$ is a unit in $\mathbb Q [x]$

Comment: @MarkBennet I guess you mean that therefore $2x^3 - 10$ is already irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$?

Comment: Thanks! Lastly if we look at the irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5})[x]$ would that give us $-2(x^2+\sqrt[3]{5}x+5^{2/3})(\sqrt[3]{5}-x)$ ?

Comment: @ExceptionalException Yes. Though I'd push that $-$ into the last factor, which then becomes $(x - \sqrt[3]{x})$. But since factorizations are only unique up to units, both are correct - it's just a matter of personal preference how you state it.

Comment: @ExceptionalException BTW, things were easy in this case because of the low degree. For a polynomial $p$ of degree 4, things get more complicated. A factorization could then consist of two polynomials of degree 2, so $p$ having no roots doesn't prevent it from having factors any more.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we notice that the polynomial does not have integer or rational roots (since thos would be one of -5, 5, -1, 1).

The polynomial is not irreducible in $Z[x]$. From the definition of irreducible polynomials: for $f(x), a(x), b(x)$ that belong to $R[x]$, $R$ ring, if $f(x)$ is not invertible, it is called irreducible if

$f(x)=a(x)b(x) => a(x)$ invertible or $b(x)$ invertible.

So in $Z[x]$, since neither $2$ nor $x^3-5$ is invertible, the polynomial is not irreducible.

From the same definition, it is irreducible in $Q[x]$, since 2 is invertible in $Q[x]$.